# error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol classes

Tags: c++

I get the error below when i call new TerrainClass() from the main, tried for hours to fix it, help please.

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall TerrainClass::TerrainClass(void)" (??0TerrainClass@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl init(void)" (?init@@YAXXZ)
```

GLDrawObject.h

```
#pragma once

class GLDrawObject
{

};
```

Terrain.cpp

```
#pragma once

TerrainClass::TerrainClass() : GLDrawObject()
{

}
```

Terrain.h

```
#pragma once

#include "GLDrawObject.h"

class TerrainClass : public GLDrawObject
{
public: 
    TerrainClass();
};
```

Comment: @DavideSpataro : The compiler generates a default constructor for `GLDrawObject`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your Terrain.cpp should be as follows:

```
#include "Terrain.h"

TerrainClass::TerrainClass() : GLDrawObject()
{

}
```

Secondly, you are getting a linker error, not a compiler error; once compiled, you need to link Terrain.o with the rest of your object files.